# Drilling down many levels (children and decendants) with jquery to get text

Tags: javascript, jquery

trying to drill down and get a name from within a `table` element. i have an id name only for the table. what is the best way of drilling down from the great-great nesting element to the desired `span`, and get its text into an `ins`?

HTML

```
....<ins id="target"></ins>...

<table id="names">
      <tbody>
      <tr>...</tr>
      <tr>
          <td>..</td>
          <td>..</td>
          <td>
              <img />
              <button>...</button>
              <span>TEXT TO GET</span>

         </td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Incomplete Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#target").text($("#names>tbody>???DRILLDOWN???).text());
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this   `$("#names").find('span').text();`

Check demo here [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j2kMs/)

Answer (score 1):

If your HTML is not change, then you can use:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#target").text($("#names>tbody tr:eq(1) td:eq(2) span").text());
});
```

But actually, it's fragile if your HTML is not stable. I'd suggest to give your span an `id` or `class` to target it more accurately instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#names tr>td>span").text();
```